# Code not being reached after button in datagrid is clicked

Tags: .net

I am working on a reporting website and currently have a datagrid with a button column. What I need is for another page to load and for a SQL query to run and populate another datagrid when one of the buttons have been clicked (but for the purpose of making the event work the second datagrid is on the same page). The issue I am having is the Sub I have created seems to be unreachable code. From my understanding the Event Handler needs to be ItemCommand. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub DataGrid2_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As DataGridCommandEventArgs) Handles DataGrid2.ItemCommand
        Dim DT1 As New DataTable
        Dim DR1 As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
            cn.ConnectionString = constr
            cn.Open()
            'not hitting the breakpoint which is why the datagrid isn't populating
            SQLstr = "long SQL query"
            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQLstr, cn)
                cmd.CommandText = SQLstr
                DR1 = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Dim DR As DataRow
                If DR1.HasRows Then
                    DT1.Load(DR1)
                    For Each col In DT1.Columns
                        col.ReadOnly = False
                    Next
                    If Not DR1 Is Nothing Then
                        DT1.Load(DR1)
                        DataGrid2.DataSource = DT1
                        DataGrid2.DataBind()
                    Else
                        DataGrid2.DataSource = Nothing
                        DataGrid2.DataBind()
                    End If
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

I introduced a break point where the sub is created but it is not hit when the button in the datagrid is clicked. Can anybody assist?

Comment: Have you bound the method to grid event? grid_onitemdatabound='method'

Comment: Are you databinding the GridView/DataGrid on postbacks? You should check the `IsPostBack` property in `Page_Load`: `If Not IsPostBack Then BindMyGrid()`

Comment: @tim how should i then declare BindMyGrid()?

Comment: @chris I do apologise but I'm fairly new to this, can you provide more details?

Comment: @ChrisWright: `BindMyGrid` is just a sample name for the method which databinds your `DataGrid`(where you set the datasource and call `DataGrid2.DataBind()`). Normally you do that in `Page_Load` but only on the first load not on postbacks since the `ViewState` retains the state of the control.

Comment: @ChrisWright Can you post the HTML for your grid (from the .aspx)

Comment: @tim thanks for your help, I just had to set the autopostback as you suggested

Comment: @ChrisWright: I haven't suggested to use `AutoPostBack` but to check the `Page.IsPostBack` property before you databind the grid.